# Execute sqlite3 "dot" commands from Python or register collation in command line utility

Tags: python, sqlite, collation

My sqlite3 database contains a "collate" column-constraint. I've placed it in the schema for the table, to prevent accidentally neglecting to use the necessary collation. However this means when running `sqlite3` from the command line, and not from my Python code, the collation referenced in the schema is not present, and I'm unable to use dot commands.

```
sqlite> .import data.txt table_name
Error: no such collation sequence: my_collation
```

Furthermore, creating the connection from Python, and adding the collation required runs into this problem:

```
connWithCollation.execute(".import data.txt table_name")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

The `execute` function it would appear does not want to pass the sqlite3 dot command through.

How can I execute sqlite3 dot commands when necessary collation functions are not present? Alternatively, how can I execute sqlite3 dot commands from Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can load new collating sequences and functions using [load_extension()](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension) built-in SQLite function or [.load](http://sqlite.org/sqlite.html) command in command line shell for SQLite. Obviously, extensions shold be written in C.

And you can not call dot-commands from python, because dot-commands are specific to the command line shell tool.

Comment: The last sentence of this answer is false. [This answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313782/2225804) shows how to do it. More generally, you can call sqlite dot commands at the command line like this `sqlite3 database.sqlite 'dot command 1' 'dot command 2'`.

Comment: @user2225804, well, certainly, you can delegate anything to another process, but installed python doesn't assume installed `sqlite3` binary. For instance, you may take a python slim docker image, it will contain the corresponding `_sqlite3....so` in `lib-dynload`, but there will be no `sqlite3` binary. But yes, you can install sqlite3 or even write in another language if you have an option.

Comment: You're imposing constraints that are not in the question. The question is "Alternatively, how can I execute sqlite3 dot commands from Python?" It doesn't say anything about avoiding subprocesses, and frankly, that doesn't even seem like a constraint most people would care about. Accepted answers should at a minimum strive for accuracy.

Answer (score 17):

You can call dot commands from Python using the subprocess module, which basically invokes a shell. If you need to use multiple dot commands, you can pass them as separate shell arguments - using a semicolon to separate them won't work.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sqlite3", "xxx.db", 
  ".mode tabs", 
  ".import file.tsv table_name"])
```

Answer (score 10):

The `.import` command in the sqlite shell is a builtin command.  It's processed by the shell program, not the SQL engine, so you can't execute it like an SQL statement.

Reading code for SQLite's [shell.c](http://www.sqlite.org/src/finfo?name=src/shell.c), it seems that `.import` is simply a loop, reading lines from the data file, splitting on the separator, and passing the fields as parameter values to a prepared `INSERT` statement.  So you should be able to mimic the behavior of `.import` with Python code easily.

I tested the following with Python 2.6:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

conn.execute('create table mytable (col1 text, col2 text, col3 text)')

csvReader = csv.reader(open('mydata.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in csvReader:
        conn.execute('insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ?)', row)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from mytable')
print cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: A great answer to half my question :)

Comment: Perfect answer/example to help anyone starting out on SQLite programming in Python!

Answer (score 8):

The dot commands are only available to the `sqlite3` executable. You will have to replace them with the equivalent combination of Python code and DB-API calls in order to mimic their behavior.

Comment: Some commands seem far away from trivial. How would you add headers or choose the column separator?

Answer (score 5):

The APSW Python wrapper for SQLite does include a shell compatible with the SQLite one.  You can also extend it to add more commands of your own choosing, extra output modes etc.  (Disclosure: I am the APSW author.)

- [APSW shell](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/shell.html)
- [Difference between APSW and pysqlite](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/pysqlite.html)

Comment: It would have been great to see your package used in an answer in: [using SQLite with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261858/does-anyone-have-example-code-for-a-sqlite-pipeline-in-scrapy).

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.run()` is preferred over`subprocess.call()`.  Below is my answer:

```
import subprocess
schema = subprocess.run(
    ['sqlite3',
     'xxx.db',
     '.schema'
    ],
    capture_output=True
).output.decode('utf-8')

print(schema)
```