# What is a good approach to filter, sort and group data stored in large text files

Tags: python, database, numpy

In a monte-carlo simulation I store a summary of each run in a data file, in which each column contains either a parameter or one of the result values. So I end up with a large data file in which up to 40 columns of data is stored, in which many rows don't have anything to do with others.

Say, for example, this file looks like that:

```
#param1    param2    result1    result2
1.0        1.0       3.14       6.28
1.0        2.0       6.28       12.56
...
2.0        1.0       1.14       2.28
2.0        2.0       2.28       4.56
```

Since I often want to study the dependence of one of the results on one of the parameters, I both need to group by the 2nd parameter and sort by the 1st one. Also, I might want to filter out rows depending on any parameters.

I started writing my own class for this, but it seems harder than one might guess. Now my question: Is there any library, that does this already? Or, since I am familiar with SQL, would it be difficult to write an SQL backend for, say, SQLAlchemy, that allows me to do simple SQL queries on my data? As far as I know, this would provide everything I need.

---

Based on the answer of cravoori (or at least the one in the link he/she posted), here is a nice and short solution to my problem:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python2

import numpy as np
import sqlite3 as sql

# number of columns to read in
COLUMNS = 31

# read the file. My columns are always 18chars long. the first line are the names
data = np.genfromtxt('compare.dat',dtype=None,delimiter=18, autostrip=True,
                     names=True, usecols=range(COLUMNS), comments=None)

# connect to the database in memory
con = sql.connect(":memory:")

# create the table 'data' according to the column names
con.execute("create table data({0})".format(",".join(data.dtype.names)))

# insert the data into the table
con.executemany("insert into data values (%s)" % ",".join(['?']*COLUMNS),
                data.tolist())

# make some query and create a numpy array from the result
res = np.array(con.execute("select DOS_Exponent,Temperature,Mobility from data ORDER \
    BY DOS_Exponent,Temperature ASC").fetchall())

print res
```

Comment: Have you considered starting with `columns = [line.split() for line in file]`? You'll have a list of all the columns for easy access and manipulation.

Comment: Depending on the data size, I would go with either some SQL solution, or, if the data is small enough, just do it all in code. How big is the data?

Comment: Lanaru: Numpy offers methods to handle column-based data files, but not to process the data very easily. It is possible, but not very short and clean code.

Comment: Nisan.H: It is not much data, but the "do it all in code" is not easy - or at least I don't know how.

Comment: What type of computation do you need to do? E.g. `Avg(param2) where Param1 = 1.0`? Generally, in code you could use a list comprehension to generate a (possibly computed) subset (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that the data is delimited, one option is to import the file into an in-memory SQLite database via the csv module, example linked below. Sqlite supports most SQL clauses

[Import data into SQLite db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854560/any-other-way-to-import-data-fileslike-csv-in-python-sqlite3-module-not-ins)

Comment: something like this looks promising. I think my files are small enough so that this would work fine. I will try it out tomorrow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only simple computations are required, the in-code approach could be something along the following lines:

```
file = open('list_filter_data.txt', mode='r')
lines = file.read().splitlines()
row_sets = [[float(c) for c in line.split()] for line in lines[1:]] # read and split the lines in the columns

# get only rows whose param1 = 1.0
subset = [row for row in row_sets if row[0] == 1.0]
print subset
# get only rows whose param1 = 2.0
subset = [row for row in row_sets if row[0] == 2.0]
print subset
# average result1 where param2 = 2.0
avg = sum([row[2] for row in row_sets if row[1] == 2.0]) / len([row[2] for row in row_sets if row[1] == 2.0])
print avg
```

Comment: This is what numpy is capable of doing as well. The thing is that it quickly grows large. Assume, I want to plot param1 vs result1 and have a different line for each param2. Also note that for the plotting I need the column-vectors, not the row vectors. It is, of course, always possible to code these transformations, but what I am looking for is a library or way to simplify this. In SQL, using where, group by and sort all this is in fact a one-liner.

Comment: Yup, this is why I think in the case of bigger data SQL is a pretty natural way to go with for this type of problem. Then maybe just use python for the file parsing for input into SQL, and the plotting of the results.

Answer (score 0):

If your file size is the order of a few MBs, you could easily read this in-memory and solve using the other answers.

If the file size is a few hundred MBs or a couple of GBs, you would be better of using a lazy loading method like the one described here - [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

If the computation you intend to do can be done row-wise, then these small chunks should be adequate for you to do whatever you need.

Else just create a SQL table with columns C1,C2,..CN for you params and results assuming it is all a one-to-one relationship between params and results. The just use python database access apis to write SQL statements and analyze whatever you need.

On the other hand, Excel spreadsheets might also solve your problem