# Does anyone have example code for a sqlite pipeline in Scrapy?

Tags: python, sqlite, export, scrapy

I am looking for some example code of a SQLite pipeline in Scrapy. I know there is no built in support for it, but I'm sure it has been done. Only actual code can help me, as I only know enough Python and Scrapy to complete my very limited task, and need the code as a starting point.

Comment: Doesn't Scrapy, which runs asynchronously, require a non-blocking datastore? In which case SQLite wouldn't work?

Comment: It seems sqlite3 is fast and smart enough to handle concurrency (up to a point). [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060772/sqlite3-concurrent-access)

Comment: It would have been great to see a solution using [APSW](https://pypi.org/project/apsw/), as the ones below are not very transparent and quite outdated.

Answer (score 16):

I did something like this:

```
#
# Author: Jay Vaughan
#
# Pipelines for processing items returned from a scrape.
# Dont forget to add pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/item-pipeline.html
#
from scrapy import log
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite

# This pipeline takes the Item and stuffs it into scrapedata.db
class scrapeDatasqLitePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Possible we should be doing this in spider_open instead, but okay
        self.connection = sqlite.connect('./scrapedata.db')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myscrapedata ' \
                    '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, url VARCHAR(80), desc VARCHAR(80))')

    # Take the item and put it in database - do not allow duplicates
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cursor.execute("select * from myscrapedata where url=?", item['url'])
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            log.msg("Item already in database: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(
                "insert into myscrapedata (url, desc) values (?, ?)",
                    (item['url'][0], item['desc'][0])

            self.connection.commit()

            log.msg("Item stored : " % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        return item

    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

Comment: A closing bracket ")" is missing after `(item['url'][0], item['desc'][0])`. it should be `(item['url'][0], item['desc'][0]))`

Answer (score 10):

Here is a sqlite pipeline with sqlalchemy. 
With sqlalchemy you can easily change your database if ever needed.

In `settings.py` add database configuration

```
# settings.py
# ...
DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'sqlite',
    # 'host': 'localhost',
    # 'port': '5432',
    # 'username': 'YOUR_USERNAME',
    # 'password': 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
    'database': 'books.sqlite'
}
```

Then in `pipelines.py` add the following

```
# pipelines.py
import logging

from scrapy import signals
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

class Book(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "books"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    author = Column('author', String)
    publisher = Column('publisher', String)
    url = Column('url', String)
    scrape_date = Column('scrape_date', DateTime)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Book({})>".format(self.url)


class SqlitePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.database = settings.get('DATABASE')
        self.sessions = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls(crawler.settings)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def create_engine(self):
        engine = create_engine(URL(**self.database), poolclass=NullPool, connect_args = {'charset':'utf8'})
        return engine

    def create_tables(self, engine):
        DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)

    def create_session(self, engine):
        session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
        return session

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        engine = self.create_engine()
        self.create_tables(engine)
        session = self.create_session(engine)
        self.sessions[spider] = session

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        session = self.sessions.pop(spider)
        session.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.sessions[spider]
        book = Book(**item)
        link_exists = session.query(Book).filter_by(url=item['url']).first() is not None

        if link_exists:
            logger.info('Item {} is in db'.format(book))
            return item

        try:
            session.add(book)
            session.commit()
            logger.info('Item {} stored in db'.format(book))
        except:
            logger.info('Failed to add {} to db'.format(book))
            session.rollback()
            raise

        return item
```

and `items.py` should look like this

```
#items.py
import scrapy

class BookItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    publisher = scrapy.Field()
    scrape_date = scrapy.Field()
```

You may also consider to move `class Book` into `items.py`

Comment: Apart from being more flexible in the DB used, this look substantially more convoluted to use than the old *pysqlite2* usage, as already described by @ibisum. Not to mention all the name-space pollution created by all the `from x import y` etc.

Comment: I like this solution better than the chosen answer for the completeness and versatility. Plus, SQLAlchemy makes dealing with db connections simple after initial configuration and utilizes an Object-Oriented approach opposed to hard-coding format-able query strings. I only have two "criticisms" of the answer and they just redundancies. `checkfirst` [defaults to True](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all). For SQLite, `poolclass` [defaults to NullPool](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#connection-pool-configuration)

Answer (score 3):

If you feel comfortable with twisted's adbapi, you can take as starting point this mysql pipeline: http://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-googledir-mysql/blob/master/googledir/pipelines.py

And use this line at `__init__`:

```
self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("sqlite3", database="/path/sqlite.db")
```

Comment: If you use sqlite3, be aware of threading requirements that require sqlite objects be used in the same thread as creation

Answer (score 3):

The following should be compatible with:

```
# Python 3.6.4
# Scrapy 1.5.1
# SQLite 3.21.0+
# APSW 3.9.2.post1
```

If you want to use [APSW](https://pypi.org/project/apsw/), just replace sqlite as noted in the comments.

If you have your **`items.py`** look like this:

```py
...
class NewAdsItem(Item):
    AdId        = Field()
    DateR       = Field()
    DateA       = Field()
    DateN       = Field()
    DateE       = Field()
    URL         = Field()   # AdURL
```

In **`settings.py`**:

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = { 
    'adbot.pipelines.DbPipeline':  100, 
}
SQLITE_FILE  = 'mad.db'
SQLITE_TABLE = 'ads'
```

In **`pipelines.py`**:

```py
import os
import sqlite3      # pip install pysqlite3
#import apsw        # pip install apsw

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.conf import settings
from adbot.items import NewAdsItem     # Get items from "items.py"

con = None
ikeys = None
class DbPipeline(object):
    dbfile  = settings.get('SQLITE_FILE')   # './test.db'
    dbtable = settings.get('SQLITE_TABLE')

    def __init__(self):
        self.setupDBCon()
        self.createTables()

    def setupDBCon(self):
        #self.con = apsw.Connection(self.dbfile)   # apsw
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(self.dbfile)    # sqlite3
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def createTables(self):
        self.dropDbTable()
        self.createDbTable()

    def dropDbTable(self):
        print("Dropping old table: %s" % self.dbtable )
        self.cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s" % self.dbtable )

    def closeDB(self):
        self.con.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.closeDB()

    def createDbTable(self):
        print("Creating new table: %s" % self.dbtable )
        #------------------------------
        # Construct the item strings:
        #------------------------------
        # NOTE: This does not work, because items.py class re-orders the items!
        #self.ikeys = NewAdsItem.fields.keys()
        #print("Keys in creatDbTable: \t%s" % ",".join(self.ikeys) )
        #cols = " TEXT, ".join(self.ikeys)  + " TEXT"
        #print("cols:  \t%s:" % cols, flush=True)
        #------------------------------
        cols = "AdId TEXT, DateR TEXT, DateA TEXT, DateN TEXT, DateE TEXT, URL TEXT"

        # NOTE:  Use "INSERT OR IGNORE", if you also use: "AdId TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE"
        sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, %s)" % (self.dbtable, cols )
        #print (sql)
        self.cur.execute(sql)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.storeInDb(item)
        return item

    def storeInDb(self, item):
        # NOTE:  Use "INSERT OR IGNORE", if you also use: "AdId TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE"
        # "INSERT INTO ads ( AdId, DateR, AdURL ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
        sql = "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})".format(self.dbtable, ','.join(item.keys()), ','.join(['?'] * len(item.keys())) )

        # (item.get('AdId',''),item.get('DateR',''),item.get('AdURL',''), ...)
        itkeys = ','.join(item.keys())      # item keys as a list
        itvals = ','.join(item.values())    # item values as a list
        ivals  = tuple(item.values())       # item values as a tuple

        #print (sql)
        #print("  itkeys: \t%s" % itkeys, flush=True)
        #print("  itvals: \t%s" % itvals, flush=True)
        self.cur.execute(sql, ivals)     # WARNING: Does NOT handle '[]'s ==> use: '' in spider

        self.con.commit()               # used in sqlite3 ONLY! (Remove for APSW)
```

You can then check your DB from command line with:

```
echo "select * from ads;" | sqlite3 -csv -header mad.db
```

---

**WARNING:**

> Because a [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714584/how-to-import-scrapy-item-keys-in-the-correct-order) in how the `items.py` item *keys* are ordered
>   when obtained via `item.keys()` or by importing your item class
>   directly via `self.ikeys = NewAdsItem.fields.keys()`, you will find
>   that the first case is sorted according to the order of appearance (in the file),
>   whereas in the second case it is *alphabetically* ordered. This is very
>   sad, since it creates trouble when you're trying to create the DB
>   tables dynamically, before having executed `process_item()`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to solve a similar problem, I just came across a nice Sqlite Item Exproter for SQLite: https://github.com/RockyZ/Scrapy-sqlite-item-exporter.

After including it to your project settings, you can use it with:

```
scrapy crawl <spider name> -o sqlite.db -t sqlite
```

It could also be adapted to be used as an Item Pipeline instead of Item Exporter.

Comment: This doesn't work, and it seem that `crawl` is deprecated as well.