# Concurrent access in SQLite

Tags: c++, c, database, sqlite

Can SQLite manage concurrent access? I use SQLite with C/C++? If it doesn't support that. Is there any suggestion to support concurrent access in SQLite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060772/sqlite3-concurrent-access

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it does as the documentation states [here](http://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html):

> SQLite Version 3.0.0 introduced a new locking and journaling mechanism
>   designed to improve concurrency over SQLite version 2 and to reduce
>   the writer starvation problem. The new mechanism also allows atomic
>   commits of transactions involving multiple database files.

and:

> SQLite uses POSIX advisory locks to implement locking on Unix. On
>   Windows it uses the LockFile(), LockFileEx(), and UnlockFile() system
>   calls.

[And here](http://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html):

> SQLite uses filesystem locks to make sure that only one process and
>   database connection is trying to modify the database at a time. The
>   filesystem locking mechanism is implemented in the VFS layer and is
>   different for every operating system. SQLite depends on this
>   implementation being correct. If something goes wrong and two or more
>   processes are able to write the same database file at the same time,
>   severe damage can result.