# Python Flask on Passenger cannot handle small numbers of concurrent requests

Tags: python, apache, passenger, wsgi

I have a Flask (Python) application running on Passenger which works absolutely fine when I test it and I'm the only user.

But as soon as I attempt to have several concurrent connections, each client waits forever for a response. I have tried it with 50 concurrent users, which seems like it should easily be supported.

The app is very simple, reading and writing to a SQLite database once or twice. (Concurrent access of SQLite by this small number of users [is not a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060838/2071807).)

What am I missing?

Comment: You're going to have to give some more information about how it's being served. sqlite is unlikely to be the bottleneck; how many processes/threads is passenger using?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for your comment. I think I have found [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42069933/2071807) (although it's hard to test until I have another 50 users to try it on.) I wanted to post this because I struggled to get help via Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Passenger docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/ruby/reloading_code.html#tmp-always_restart-txt) it makes the following suggestion:

> Passenger also supports the magic file 'tmp/always_restart.txt'. If
>   this file exists, Passenger will restart your application after every
>   request. This way you do not have to invoke the restart command often.
>
> Activate this mechanism by creating the file:
>
> `$ mkdir -p tmp`
>
> `$ touch tmp/always_restart.txt`

This is great for development because it means you only need to save your Python files for the latest version of the app to be available to clients.

But it's terrible for production because every client makes its own request and that restarts the Python app. This is a very major overhead for the server, so users are likely to timeout before receiving a response.

Delete the file `tmp/always_restart.txt` and your concurrency limits will shoot up.