# Can i use Cassandra database in electron

Tags: node.js, sqlite, cassandra, electron

I am already using sqlite which comes binaries , so when build electron it compiles  with respect to native os.so no prerequisites to install and use my application.

in the same way can i able to use cassandra in electron ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no sense - Cassandra is the distributed system, and designed to run in clusters of several nodes. Besides this, it has relatively high requirements for memory, and CPU, so your users won't be happy if your app will require at least 2Gb of RAM and multicore CPU to run.

You need to define what you kind of operations you want to perform, and then select database. If you need something like key-value store, you can use RocksDB, for example, etc.

Comment: thank you , i want achieve parallel writes to db. i previously using sqlite and it offers one write at one time, so only think about other database options. Cassandra promises to offer concurrent writes. Is there any way ?

Comment: I suggest to search for other embed-able databases - I mentioned RocksDB. Or you can take Derby, or something else. It's all depends on your requirements - what kind of queries you need to perform, etc.

Comment: *so your users won't be happy if your app will require at least 2Gb of RAM and multicore CPU to run.* OP is using Electron already...

Comment: @Shawn it will be addition to that

Answer (score 1):

> Ian: Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should

In short, You can use any DB and build an electron app. But are you sure its the right choice, when considering a small tiny hello world app in electron takes up  150 MB?

Comment: I want to achieve concurrent writes at the same time . but sqlite allows one write at one time, is there any other db offers parallel writes ??

Comment: can you please tell me, what stack are you using to build your project? Electron is nothing but a wrapper that has a V8 engine. Are you using javascript in your backend as well? if that's the case, I don't think javascript provides multithreading readily. How are you planning to achieve this concurrent write? And As I said, There is nothing wrong with using Cassandra DB. Its electron I am worried about.

Comment: nodejs in the backend, yes it is single threaded , i used to call write db using async for loop.  but it takes more time.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a while, i seen this helpful links

[Link1](https://www.skoumal.com/en/parallel-read-and-write-in-sqlite/)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060772/sqlite-concurrent-access)