# Multithread in Sqlite DB

Tags: python, c++, sqlite

I am using SQlite db, two application uses this db, one from C++ and another from python. If a table is accessed by both the application simultaneously, Database error occurs. How to use same db in two application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite Concurrent Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060772/sqlite-concurrent-access)

Comment: SQLite is a great tool but it has one big limitation: it is not intended for concurrent accesses. If you really need that, you should use a different database like PostgreSQL or MariaDB.

Comment: I can tell you that WAL mode helps. It does not eliminate the need for error handling however.