# Concurrent access to one file by several unrelated processes on macOS

Tags: python, macos, concurrency, ipc

I need to get several processes to communicate with each others on a macOS system. These processes will be spawned several times per day at different times, and I cannot predict when they will be up at the same time (if ever). These programs are in [python](https://www.python.org/) or [swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/).

How can I safely allow these programs to all write to the same file?

I have explored a few different options:

- I thought of using [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), however I couldn't find an answer in the documentation on whether it was safe to write concurrently across processes. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060772/sqlite-concurrent-access) is not very definitive, old, and I would ideally like to get a more authoritative answer.
- I thought of using [multiprocesing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) as it supports locks. However, as far as I could see in the documentation, you need a meta-process that spawns the children and stays up for the duration of the longest child process. I am am fine having a meta-spawner process, but it feels wasteful to have a meta-process basically staying up all day long, just to resolve conflicting access ?
- Along the lines of this, I thought of having a process that stays up all day long, and receive messages from all other processes, and is the sole responsible for writing to file. It feels a little wasteful, how worried should I be about the resource cost of having a program up all day, and doing little? Are the only thing to worry about memory footprint and CPU usage (as shown in activity monitor), or could there be other significant costs, e.g. context switching?
- I have come across [flock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) on linux, that seems to be a locking mechanism to access files, provided by the OS. This seems like a good solution, but this does not seem to exist on macOS?

Any idea to solve this requirement in a robust manner (so that I don't have to debug every other day - I now concurrency can be a pain), is most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are in control of the source code of all such processes, you could use flock. It will put the *advisory* lock on file, so the other writer will be blocked only in case he is also access the file the same way. This is OK for you, if only your processes will ever need to write to the shared file.
I've tested flock on BigSur, it is still implemented and works fine.

You can also do it in any other common manner: create temporary .lock file in the known location(this is what git does), and remove it after current writer is done with the main file; use semaphores; etc