# SQLite database not inserting all simultaneous inserts, returning the same IDs for those that didn't get an insert

Tags: sqlite

I have a React website with an node express back end. I have created an upload functionality that uses an SQLite database to save the details of the uploaded files. Of course, the functionality runs asynchronously. The problem I am facing is that when I test uploading multiple files simultaneously, I am getting results from the back end with SQLite records with identical IDs.

The table in question does have an ID field that is a PK, Unique, and auto incrementing. This is a snapshot of the Id field from the designer:

[image]

Below is my code to insert a new record to my table. I get the inserted record's ID with `RETURNING Id`.

```
            const insertSql = `INSERT INTO ${this.TableName} (\n` +
                              "   UploaderId,\n" +
                              "   ExtensionId,\n" +
                              "   Size,\n" +
                              "   FileName,\n" +
                              "   IsStaging,\n" +
                              "   Created)\n" +
                              "VALUES (\n" +
                              `   ${uploaderId},\n` +
                              `   ${extension.Id},\n` +
                              `   ${fileSize},\n` +
                              "   ?,\n" +
                              "   1,\n" +
                              `   '${SysTrick.NowToUtcString()}')\n` +
                              "RETURNING Id;\n";

            const insertResult = await Db.GetAsync(insertSql, nameDetails.NameSanExtension);

            if (!SysTrick.IsNull(insertResult?.Id))
            {
                result.Id = SysTrick.SafeInteger(insertResult.Id);
            }
```

However I get this result below when I upload multiple files simultaneously. I have highlighted the IDs in red that are not unique.

[image]

However, this doesn't mean that there are multiple records in the database with identical IDs. They are all unique, as this image shows:

[image]

It just means that I have uploaded files that never got an SQLite record created for them. E.g., for files "85.jpg" and "89.jpg" that share the same record ID 226, it is "89.jpg" that is recorded having the ID in the table. "85.jpg" ends up not having a record in SQLite.

I have tried searching for this problem on the web, but could not find anything.

I have tried doing transactions, but I am getting syntax errors. Besides, this should not be necessary, since the database should be able to handle asynchronous inserts.

Is this an intrinsic SQLite problem? If it is, then it's not a very useful database to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4060772/1030675

Comment: What happens if you put an `else` clause on `if (!SysTrick.IsNull(insertResult?.Id))`  and a try / catch around `await Db.GetAsync(...` ? It's possible some of your INSERTs are failing,

Comment: I don't need the else, it means the file will not get an ID (null), which should show up in the result. I also already have a try...catch. I'm getting deadlocks. I sleep the query and try again.