# Storing scraped data into the database sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy

I have used scarpy to scrap some text from a website. But I am not quite sure how to store them in sqlite?Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: You need to define a Pipeline like suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261858/does-anyone-have-example-code-for-a-sqlite-pipeline-in-scrapy), or use an item exporter, like [this](https://github.com/RockyZ/Scrapy-sqlite-item-exporter) one. Also see this [scrapy-dblite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-dblite/0.2.5) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while you can find some examples that are using **blocking** operations to interact with the database it is worth noting that scrapy is built on top of twisted library, meaning that in its core there is only a single thread with a single loop for all operations, so when you do something like:

```
self.cursor.execute(...)
```

the entire system is waiting for a response from the database, including http requests that are waiting to be executed etc.

having said that, I suggest you'll check this code snippet https://github.com/riteshk/sc/blob/master/scraper/pipelines.py

using `twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool` is a little more complex than a simple blocking database access code but it plays well with the way scrapy uses io operations