# Issues with SQLite Table - Specifically foreign keys

Tags: python, database, sqlite, web-scraping, scrapy

Okay the main issue I am having is I have a table that should not have any duplicate entries. This is because I was hoping to have a Primary Key which would be referenced in a separate table.

From what I understand about normalization it is better to have your database designed in this fashion. So right now I have a table that has a bunch of duplicate entries (there should be only 6 unique entries but there are 30 entries, each unique one is repeated 5 times).

How should I fix this? Should I fix this when importing the data, or by using a UNIQUE keyword. To note when I tried to use the UNIQUE feature this time around, it gave me an error as the data that I am importing indeed has duplicates entries.

EDIT:

This is what my items looks like:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class TeamStats(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()

    team = Field()
    division = Field()
    rosterurl = Field()
    player_desc = Field()
    playerurl = Field()
    pass

class Player(Item):
    exp = Field()
    pass
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
import scrapy
import string
import re
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector                                                                       ##needed to import xpath command
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response                                                                           ##needed for Response object
from nbastats.items import TeamStats, Player                                                                  ##needed to import player stats


class NbastatsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nbaStats"

    start_urls = [
        "http://espn.go.com/nba/teams"                                                                              ##only start not allowed because had some issues when navigated to team roster pages
        ]
    def parse(self,response):
        items = []                                                                                                  ##array or list that stores TeamStats item
        i=0                                                                                                         ##counter needed for older code

        for division in response.xpath('//div[@id="content"]//div[contains(@class, "mod-teams-list-medium")]'):     
            for team in division.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "mod-content")]//li'):
                item = TeamStats()

                item['division'] = division.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "mod-header")]/h4/text()').extract()[0]            
                item['team'] = team.xpath('.//h5/a/text()').extract()[0]
                item['rosterurl'] = "http://espn.go.com" + team.xpath('.//div/span[2]/a[3]/@href').extract()[0]
                items.append(item)
                print(item['rosterurl'])
                request = scrapy.Request(item['rosterurl'], callback = self.parseWPNow)
                request.meta['play'] = item

                yield request

    def parseWPNow(self, response):
        item = response.meta['play']
        item = self.parseRoster(item, response)
        return item

    def parseRoster(self, item, response):
        players1 = []
        int = 0
        for players in response.xpath("//td[@class='sortcell']"):
            play = {}
            play['name'] = players.xpath("a/text()").extract()[0]
            play['position'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[1]").extract()[0]
            play['age'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[2]").extract()[0]
            play['height'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[3]").extract()[0]
            play['weight'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[4]").extract()[0]
            play['college'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[5]").extract()[0]
            play['salary'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[6]").extract()[0]
            players1.append(play)
        item['playerurl'] = response.xpath("//td[@class='sortcell']/a").extract()
        item['player_desc']=players1
        return item
```

This is what my pipeline looks like:

```
class NbastatsPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.setupDBCon()
        self.createTables()

    def setupDBCon(self):
        self.con = lite.connect('test.db')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def createTables(self):
        self.dropTeamsTable()
        self.dropPlayersTable()
        self.dropDivsTable()

        self.createTeamsTable()
        self.createPlayersTable()
        self.createDivsTable()

    def createTeamsTable(self):
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Teams(P_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, \
            team TEXT, \
            DivId INTEGER, \
            FOREIGN KEY (DivId) REFERENCES Divs1(Did) \
            )")

    def createDivsTable(self):
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Divs(Did INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, \
            division TEXT)")

    def createPlayersTable(self):
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Players(player_name TEXT, \
            salary TEXT, \
            weight INTEGER, \
            age INTEGER, \
            college TEXT )")

    def dropTeamsTable(self):
        self.cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Teams")
    def dropPlayersTable(self):
        self.cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Players")
    def dropDivsTable(self):
        self.cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Divs")

    def closeDB(self):
        self.con.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.closeDB()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        for key, value in item.iteritems():
            if key == "division":
                print(item.get('division', ""))
                self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Divs( division ) VALUES(?)", (item.get('division', ""),))
                self.con.commit() 
#                self.storeInDb(item) #this is the line you'll use when ready to completely pass item through to storeInDb but it'll be lower in code

        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to *enforce uniqueness on the database level* and handle it in your application.

For Scrapy specifically, if you insert the records *in the pipeline*, usually you have a construction like this:

```
import sqlite3
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem     

try:
    cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO 
            table 
            (field1, field2) 
        VALUES (?, ?)""", (field1, field2))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    raise DropItem('Duplicate entry')
```

See also examples of sqlite pipelines:

- [Does anyone have example code for a sqlite pipeline in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261858/does-anyone-have-example-code-for-a-sqlite-pipeline-in-scrapy)
- [pipeline from scrapy-examples](https://github.com/feiskyer/Scrapy-Examples/blob/master/blog_crawl/blog_crawl/pipelines.py)

---

There is also a project called [`scrapy-dblite`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-dblite) which provides a nice abstraction - you are not going down to SQL queries, there is a simple ORM built-in. For example:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from myproject.items import Product
import dblite

class StoreItemsPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ds = None

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.ds = open(Product, 'sqlite://db/products.sqlite:items', autocommit=True)

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.ds.commit()
        self.ds.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, Product):
            try:
                self.ds.put(item)
            except dblite.DuplicateItem:
                raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            raise DropItem("Unknown item type, %s" % type(item))
        return item
```

Comment: Enforcing uniqueness on a database level and handling it in my application means I would do something like creating a list in my application and passing that to my table (the table that would only house those 6 entries with their primary keys autoincremented) correct?

I'm just a little confused because I have a table with these 6 unique entries, then another table that references this column via primary keys, so that means I would have to make this list just for the sake of having numbers (foreign key) in the one row rather strings.

Comment: @user3042850 okay, let's try to clear this up. Could you please show the tables you have in the database and items you have in the scrapy project?

Comment: So right now I'm trying to fill the divs table with Unique NBA Divisions, of which there are 6. However 5 teams reside in each division, so due to normalization, I don't want to have that column have repeat data, in the Teams table, so I've created a Divs table to house that information. I then hope to just insert the divisions as a foreign key into the Teams table. Umm if that's not the format you were hoping for, I can definitely try and put it into a format that's easier on the eyes.

Comment: Sorry to keep bombarding you with comments, but I just need help with this one thing because I'm just unsure how to go about implementing this primary key thing, I think I understand how to use it and when to use it but like this will just force me to develop my code to produce outputs in certain formats.

Comment: I don't know how much experience you have with Scrapy but I was also hoping you'd be able to answer the question that if my SQL column headings need to be the same as my Item properties. I ask this because I think I had one be different and it threw me an error (sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: 'incorrect name i inputted on purpose'). It's odd though because it seems I can input an ID with no trouble.

Comment: @user3042850 here is what I'm think about it: I'd create an item class for each entity you have in the database: `Player`, `Team`, `Division`. In the spider I'd instantiate and yield/return different items - when you scrape the division name name - yield an item with it, same for player and team. In the pipeline, try inserting into the tables and handle integrity errors (duplicate entries). Anyway, I would start with redesigning the tables you currently have. For instance, you probably need a unique check for division name, a player should probably have a foreign key to a team etc.

Comment: @user3042850 and this is too many questions for a single thread. Try splitting up the problem into steps and solve it step by step, starting from designing your database tables. If you have difficulties consider asking separate questions here on SO. Thanks.