# How to import Scrapy item keys in the correct order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am importing the Scrapy item keys from `items.py`, into `pipelines.py`. 
The problem is that the **order** of the imported items are different from how they were defined in the `items.py` file.

My `items.py` file:

```
class NewAdsItem(Item):
    AdId        = Field()
    DateR       = Field()
    AdURL       = Field()
```

In my `pipelines.py`:

```
from adbot.items import NewAdsItem
...
def open_spider(self, spider):
     self.ikeys = NewAdsItem.fields.keys()
     print("Keys in pipelines: \t%s" % ",".join(self.ikeys) )
     #self.createDbTable(ikeys)
```

The output is:

```
Keys in pipelines:  AdId,AdURL,DateR
```

instead of the expected: `AdId,DateR,AdURL`.

**How can I ensure that the imported order remains the same?**

**Note:** This might be related to [How to get order of fields in Scrapy item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293916/how-to-get-order-of-fields-in-scrapy-item), but it's not at all very clear what's going on, since Python3 docs state that lists and dicts should retain their order. Also note, that when using `process_item()` and using `item.keys()`, the order is retained! But I need to access the *keys* in order *before* *item*'s are scraped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work, was to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899166/1147688) in the following manner.

My **`items.py`** file:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from collections import OrderedDict
from types import FunctionType

class StaticOrderHelper(type):
    # Requires Python3
    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs):
        return OrderedDict()

    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        namespace['_field_order'] = [
                k
                for k, v in namespace.items()
                if not k.startswith('__') and not k.endswith('__')
                    and not isinstance(v, (FunctionType, classmethod, staticmethod))
        ]
        return type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

class NewAdsItem(metaclass=StaticOrderHelper):
    AdId        = Field()
    DateR       = Field()
    AdURL       = Field()
```

Then import the `_field_order` item into your **`piplines.py`** with:

```
...
from adbot.items import NewAdsItem
...
class DbPipeline(object):
    ikeys = NewAdsItem._field_order
    ...
    def createDbTable(self):
        print("Creating new table: %s" % self.dbtable )
        print("Keys in creatDbTable: \t%s" % ",".join(self.ikeys) )
        ...
```

I can now create new DB tables in the correct order of appearance, without worrying of Python's weird way of sorting dicts in unexpected ways.

Answer (score -1):

A simple fix is to define `keys()` method in your `Item` class:

```
class MyItem(Item):
    foo = Field()
    bar = Field()
    gar = Field()
    cha = Field()

    def keys(self):
        # in your preferred order
        return ['cha', 'gar','bar','foo']
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I still get the alphabetical order `AdId,AdURL,DateR`.Are you using Python2? (I am using Python3).

Comment: Hmm I've only used this ages ago, maybe newer versions of scrapy no longer support keys overriding anymore, gonna test it.

Comment: You can test it from the scrapy shell, by importing the items.py. Has no effect at all. at least for me.