# formating dot commands in sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My first SQL database Im using sqlite3 in idle on linux. Everything is working fine but I want my table to display in an easier to read format in the terminal. Been reading about dot commands eg `.mode column` or `.headers on` but not sure were to put it in my code, I think this is the closest:

```
def veiw_outstanding_job():
cursorObj = con.cursor()

cursorObj.execute('.mode column\nSELECT * FROM '+ VesselName + ' WHERE State = "outstanding" ')

rows = cursorObj.fetchall()

for row in rows:

    print(row)
menu()
```

but i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/run.py", line 559, in runcode
    exec(code,self.locals)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Maintenance Manager/Maintenanceanager.py", line 238, in <module>
    menu()
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Maintenance Manager/Maintenance Manager.py", line 27, in menu
    veiw_job(con)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Maintenance Manager/Maintenance Manager.py", line 54, in veiw_job
    cursorObj.execute('.mode column\nSELECT * FROM '+ VesselName) sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".":
syntax error
```

(also asked on database admin stackexchange and got sent here)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute sqlite3 "dot" commands from Python or register collation in command line utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346074/execute-sqlite3-dot-commands-from-python-or-register-collation-in-command-line)

Comment: Tracebacks should be formatted as if code to preserve line formatting.  The code in your question is not what you ran as it has additional SyntaxErrors.